# Window Click to Focus Without Passing Event To App

Tags: unity, mouse, focus

I like the click-to-focus behavior, but is there some way to prevent the window from receiving the click event until after it has been focused?  Example, I click a window in the background to bring it to front, but in doing so I accidentally click some button or link in the window.  Can I have the WM just bring the window to the front, but not send that click event into the window?